# OAuthentication error with Gmail for android app

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying to build a client app for Gmail on android, (I have seen that there are a lot of questions on this).

(I have seen the question similar to this : [How to integrate Gmail Api in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136085/how-to-integrate-gmail-api-in-android-app). But my problem isn't with the SHA1-Key)

I am using the link given in the Andorid developer site: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

I have made the first activity based on this and have also created the API access in the google developers console.

I am using the usingOAuth to get the credentials ,

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

I am able to view the list of mail IDs that are configured in my phone, and when I select one I call the method in the Async service :

```
public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("mailclient")
                .build();
    }
```

This only goes to the onCancelled() method in the Async service and provides the error

```
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err: {
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     "domain" : "usageLimits",
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     "message" : "Access Not Configured. Gmail API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail/overview?project=608941808256"
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:   } ],
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:   "message" : "Access Not Configured. Gmail API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err: }
10-20 01:58:23.456 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.getDataFromApi(MainActivity.java:358)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:340)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:320)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-20 01:58:23.457 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-20 01:58:32.709 13659-13659/sevenre.dinesh.de.com.mailclient W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

The URL that the app tries to connect to is not a proper one

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail/overview?project=608941808256
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here, the only thing I believe I have to do is give either the API or Client ID somewhere in the App. But I am not sure where should I give those constants ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if your Gmail API and other APIs that you also use have already been enabled in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). To enable it, select Gmail API from API menu then please click on enable if you haven't done so (photo shown below).

[image: enable Gmail API]

Additionally, you may want to also check this [GitHub post](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/111) or this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144299/access-not-configured-the-api-google-api-is-not-enabled-for-your-project-pl).

Comment: For the same code, when I ran it on android 2.2 (before it was android 1.4) I got it to work. I am not sure what the problem was, I should look on it. But for now I have it working.